# Making a dynamic function from a string callable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is tied to Dan Bader's schedule package. From what I understand, you schedule function calls. That's pretty simple if you are defining the function in your script. However, what about functions that are built dynamically using exec()? Is there any way to make these callable? I keep getting errors when trying to schedule these functions. I recognize that this is likely not the best idea (maybe not even a good idea), but this is just for a POC and I'm still curious if this can be done.

```
def buildJob(lang, repType, name, file='', recipient='', server = '', db='', path=''):
    today = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.today(), '%m%d%Y%H%M%S')
    filePath = f"{c.path}{name}-{today}".replace('\\', '/')
    filename = f'{name}-{today}.xlsx'
    funcText = f"""
def {name}():
    sql = ("{file}")
    filePath = ("{filePath}")
    engine = sa.create_engine(conString)
    dat = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
    engine.dispose()
    del engine
    buildSpreadsheet(dat, filePath)
    sendSpreadsheet("{recipient}", "{filePath}.xlsx", "{filename}")
        """
```

I then have a function to grab the funcText and exec() it. However, when I pass this into schedule, it says that the argument must be callable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `globals()['function_name']`?

Comment: Why are you doing that instead of just creating a closure? All of the "dynamic" stuff seem to be plain variables, it's not like the actual function code is templated.

Comment: Depending on the use case, this approach can provide better error messages, as the resulting function isn't defined by another function. (The `namedtuple` class was originally defined in a similar fashion, constructing a giant `class` statement executed by `exec`. It was eventually re-implemented in C for performance, but as a POC, it's not a terrible starting point.)

Comment: Regarding globals()['function_name'], when I try that, I'm getting a key error saying that the function name is not found...and that's after the exec(). That said, when I walk through the steps manually in the terminal, the function is definitely there

Comment: Where is the `exec()` occurring? If it's within a function it will be in local scope.

Comment: @Masklinn, I'm interested in the closure idea, but schedule expects to run a specific function. For my POC, I've built a system where people can schedule reports. So, that's why I built dynamic functions...so each report could be different and run at different times. With a closure, I'm not sure that would work since everything would fall under a single function.

Comment: @Axe319, Yea, the exec IS happening in a function and I agree that this is a huge part of the problem. I'm just having issues making the dynamic functions global and callable.

Comment: @swaters See my local scope example below. `locals()['name']` should be called within the function the `exec` is happening. Then you can return it as a first order function and bind it to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve defined functions with the `locals()` and `globals()` `dict`s.

```
# in global scope
as_str = f"""
def foo():
    print('foo')
"""
exec(as_str)
foo = globals()['foo']
foo()

# in function scope
def bar():
   as_str = f"""
def baz():
    print('baz')
""" 
   exec(as_str)
   return locals()['baz']

baz = bar()
baz()
```

Someone may correct me but dynamic function creation with `exec` seems like a bad idea. Especially if the input isn't being sanitized.